# Como filtrar datos por el resultado de una suma

Tags: sql-server

que tal, estoy haciendo una consulta en SQL Server, y quiero filtrar la consulta cuando el resultado de una suma sea menor a 600, mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT l.Id_Linea, l.Descripcion, SUM(dp.Pares)AS TotalPares
FROM Dpedido AS dp
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy.dbo.Producto AS p ON p.Id_producto = dp.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy.dbo.Linea AS l ON l.Id_Linea = p.Id_Linea
WHERE dp.Estatus = 10 AND TotalPares < 600
GROUP BY l.Id_Linea, l.Descripcion
```

Ya intente con **HAVING**, pero el campo **TotalPares** en la base de datos no existe no funciona. Me pueden decir una manera de resolver esta parte.

Comment: Como pusiste el having?? esto se soluciona con el having ;) having sum(dp.Pares) < 600

Comment: Creo que lo había puesto como continuación en la clausula **where**,  y eso me pedía un campo que estuviera en mi BD, pero en la respuesta que me dieron aqui se usa como otra condicion o clausula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en la clausula `HAVING` no debes poner el alias sino la función de agregado. Tu consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT l.Id_Linea, 
       l.Descripcion, 
       SUM(dp.Pares)AS TotalPares
FROM Dpedido AS dp
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy.dbo.Producto AS p ON p.Id_producto = dp.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN ProduccionPhy.dbo.Linea AS l ON l.Id_Linea = p.Id_Linea
WHERE dp.Estatus = 10 
GROUP BY l.Id_Linea, l.Descripcion
HAVING SUM(dp.Pares) < 600;
```

Comment: Este me funciono muy bien gracias

Comment: En la mayoria de las bases de datos, el alias de los campos se resuelve al finalizar la query.... por eso no se usan los alias...